# Expanding lists with split strings

Tags: list-manipulation

I've got data of the type:

```
list = {"Class","MW","10 - 11"}
```

which I would like to split into a number of lists based on the number of characters in the second list element.  In the above case, the desired output would be:

```
newlists = {{"Class","M","10-11"},{"Class","W","10-11"}}
```

`StringSplit[list[[2]],""]` gets me in the right direction (the string I want to split will always be in the same position in the list); however, I don't know how to thread this new sublist through the original list.

Comment: Guessing where you're going with this, you might want to look at [Generating schedules/timetables in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5181)

Comment: @rm-rf Wish I had posted this question **before** writing the grid layout code...

Comment: did I really write one of those answers? sloppy stuff... :)

Comment: @cormullion I found it ironic that a 10k+ rep'er was referring to others as 'experts'.  I wonder if SE gives us a way to see what the rep was when a person answered the question.

Comment: @bobthechemist You can find a user's network profile from their site profile. From there, the reputation tab has a nice plot that you can use to quickly find out what the user's rep was on a given date.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's how you can thread them:

```
newlists = Thread[{#, Characters@#2, ##3}] & @@ list
(* {{"Class", "M", "10 - 11"}, {"Class", "W", "10 - 11"}} *)
```

Comment: Is there a less ambiguous way to map this command over a list of list: `Thread[{#, Characters@#2, ##3}]& @@ # & /@ multilists`?  I don't know how concerned I should be about nested pure functions.

Comment: @bobthechemist `Thread[{#, Characters@#2, ##3}] & @@@ multilists` you can also add `// Flatten[#, 1] &` if you need.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an approach that doesn't use threading.

```
data = {"Class", "MW", "10 - 11"};
{a, b, c} = data;
new = {a, #, c} & /@ Characters @ b
```

> ```
> {{"Class", "M", "10 - 11"}, {"Class", "W", "10 - 11"}}
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
Distribute[MapAt[Characters, list, {2}], List] (* or *)
Distribute[MapAt[StringSplit[#, ""]&, list, {2}], List]
```

> {{"Class", "M", "10 - 11"}, {"Class", "W", "10 - 11"}}

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not handy but interesting way to apply automatic threading:

```
SetAttributes[h, Listable];
h @@ MapAt[Characters, list, {2}] /. h -> List
```

> ```
> {{"Class", "M", "10 - 11"}, {"Class", "W", "10 - 11"}}
> ```

```
multilist = {{"Class", "MW", "10 - 11"}, {"Class", "MK", "10 - 11"}}

h @@@ MapAt[Characters, multilist, {All, 2}] /. h -> List
```

> ```
> {{{"Class", "M", "10 - 11"}, {"Class", "W", "10 - 11"}}, 
>    {{"Class", "M", "10 - 11"}, {"Class", "K", "10 - 11"}}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
fun[u_] := Module[{dow},
  dow = Characters[#[[2]]] &@u;
  ReplacePart[u, 2 -> #] & /@ dow]
```